# Disadvantages mutating state directly and forceUpdate() vs setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React docs say `Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable...` But this is a non issue when I don't use setState() at all.

The only disadvantages I can think of are:

- Can't use `shouldComponentUpdate`/`componentWillUpdate`/`componentDidUpdate` to compare old and new state.
- Will probably make maintainability harder for others working on it. Since it's not the standard way to do things.

But are there any **other** disadvantages to not using setState() and mutating state directly?

---

**EDIT:** I've deleted my reasoning why I'm attracted to that idea. I know it's an anti-pattern and I know it's probably not the best way to do it. But this question is all about "why".

**EDIT2:** Also key word here is `other` in `... are there any other disadvantages ...`

Comment: *"My reasoning behind it is that most of the problems I encounter in React development is due to async nature of setState."* Like what? Usually when you're tripping over a central part of a well-developed, well-used framework, it's because you're following anti-patterns without realizing. Rather than bypass the framework, find out why you're tripping over things.

Comment: Interesting question, I'd happily upvote all the answers that mention specific downsides of this approach

Answer (score 4):

You should not directly mutate the state. Async nature of setState has ways to get around it. `setState` provides a `callback` that you can use.

Also forceUpdate completely bypasses the `shouldComponentUpdate` which is not a good pattern especially when using `React.PureComponent` that does a shallow comparison of your props.

Also you should not use anti patterns, rather try to solve your issues the correct way suggested by the docs

> The other advantage of using `setState` that you may loose with this
>   pattern is to compare your `previous` and the `currentState` since you
>   made the object `mutable` especially in your lifecycle functions
>
> A drawback setting state directly is that React's lifecycle
>   methods - `shouldComponentUpdate()`, `componentWillUpdate()`,
>   `componentDidUpdate()` - depend on state transitions being called with
>   `setState()`. If you change the state directly and call `setState()` with
>   an empty object, you can no longer implement those methods.

Also You may know personally that your code interacts with React in such a way that these over-writes or other issues can't happen but you're creating a situation where other developers or future updates can suddenly find themselves with weird or subtle issues when they start following the right approach

Using setState to mutate state

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state =  {
      counter: 0
  }
  updateCounter = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}));
  }
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    console.log(this.state.counter === nextState.counter);
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     console.log(this.state.counter === prevState.counter);
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.counter}
          <button onClick={this.updateCounter}>Increment</button>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Directly mutating state

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state =  {
      counter: 0
  }
  updateCounter = () => {
    this.state.counter =  this.state.counter + 1;
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    console.log(this.state.counter === nextState.counter);
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
     console.log(this.state.counter === prevState.counter);
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          {this.state.counter}
          <button onClick={this.updateCounter}>Increment</button>
        </div>
      )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I've downvoted you because the question doesn't ask what's the correct way to set state in react. I know about callbacks, I know about `shouldComponentUpdate` (it's even in question). I understand that this approach would be an anti-pattern. **But, I want to understand why's that an anti-pattern.**

Comment: As I said in my answer, if you use forceUpdate it bypasses shouldComponentUpdate, and if you use PureComponent that optimizes in the shouldComponentUpdate you are affecting the performance

Comment: I see your edits but it's still not the answer for my question. My question was what are the other disadvantages, excluding maintainability & state comparison in component lifecycles like `shouldComponentUpdate`, because I know about these ones.

Comment: I added two snippets for you.If  state comparison in lifecylce method is not a drawback then what is a drawback for you. You are completely making the Framework useless without the lifecycle function

Comment: I added two snippets for you.If  state comparison in lifecylce method is not a drawback then what is a drawback for you. You are completely making the Framework useless without the lifecycle function

Comment: I agree with you it is a major drawback, but the question was what are the **other** disadvantages.

Comment: If you directly mutate the state, and lets say you update 2 props without using setState, the operation will be not done atomic and the listeners will be updated twice even worse with not-expected states. But if you perform with setState the update of the 2 values will be atomic and the listeners will face both the updated values at the same time.