# Using forceUpdate instead of setState in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have a react component, and I just set its class variables, ie

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.numberElements = 20;
      this.color = 'red';
    }

    render() { 
       ...
    }
}
```

Can't I just call `this.forceUpdate()` to issue a re-render (whenever I update my class variables) instead of maintaining a state and calling `setState`?. Or is it bad to do that, and if so, why?

Comment: Yeah it's bad practise, there is a reason why lifecyle events and setState / props are there. If you need to use forceUpdate then it indicates that you are doing something wrong, imho

Comment: This might throw more light on it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47237556/disadvantages-mutating-state-directly-and-forceupdate-vs-setstate/47237601#47237601

Answer (score 4):

`forceUpdate()` is actually useful in scenarios like the one you're describing.

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate):

> By default, when your component’s state or props change, your component will re-render. If your `render()` method depends on some other data, you can tell React that the component needs re-rendering by calling `forceUpdate()`.

The caveat, however, is that it will skip `shouldComponentUpdate()`, so you're not getting the optimization benefit.

Also, using `forceUpdate()` "bypasses" the proper lifecycle, making your code less straight-forward and possibly harder to understand and maintain.

It is therefore recommended to use `state` and `props` when possible.

> Normally you should try to avoid all uses of forceUpdate() and only read from `this.props` and `this.state` in render().

Comment: "`forceUpdate()` is actually useful in scenarios like the one you're describing." What scenario? Op just said "... and I just set its class variables ...". I don't see any justification for not going through the proper process. Unless OP can find a more compelling reason than "I just felt like it", I'm inclined to agree with Icepickle and Shubham Khatri.

Comment: not completely sold yet. forceUpdate() and class variables still seems easier to me and I don't need shouldComponentUpdate.