# Passing instance variables from one child component to another in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some trouble understanding how to pass **component instance variables** in **React** ([live example](https://jsfiddle.net/sbilinski/69z2wepo/330622/)). My hierarchy is as follows:

```
DataView
 |> SharedScale
 |> Graph1
 |> Graph2
 |> ...
```

The idea is to create a **shared, D3 axis/scale** in `SharedScale` and pass it to all other graphs via the `DataView` wrapper (i.e. a reference scale is supposed to be shown at the top of the page). The scale implementation can change, when the component is resized for example (i.e. it's created in the `render` function in my case):

```
class SharedScale extends React.Component {    
  render() {  
    // Create a D3 scale; i.e. an external library object, which is not serializable
    this.scaleImpl = ...

    // Render a D3 axis using the scale implementation
    return <div>{this.scaleImpl}</div>; 
  }
};
```

The `Graph` is supposed to get a reference to `SharedScale`, and render a **D3 chart**, based on it:

```
class Graph extends React.Component {
   render() {    
     //Use the scaleImpl here to render the graph body
     return (
       <div>{get(this.props, "scaleComponent.scaleImpl", "no scale implementation")}</div>
     );
   }
}
```

I'm trying to combine this together in the `DataView`, using `React.createRef` as such:

```
class DataView extends React.Component {   
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.scaleComponent = React.createRef();
    }

    render() {
        return(
          <div>
            <SharedScale ref={this.scaleComponent} />
            <Graph scaleComponent={this.scaleComponent.current} />                
          </div>
        );
     }
}
```

The problem is that the `render()` function is only called once. That is, the `current` field is consistently `null`.

Am I missing something, or is this approach fundamentally flawed for some reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, one can trigger an additional `render` event by calling `forceUpdate` in `componentDidMount`:

```
class DataView extends React.Component {   
  ...

  componentDidMount() {
    this.forceUpdate();
  }
}
```

From [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) reference page:

> You may call setState() immediately in componentDidMount(). It will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the render() will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state. Use this pattern with caution because it often causes performance issues. In most cases, you should be able to assign the initial state in the constructor() instead. It can, however, be necessary for cases like modals and tooltips when you need to measure a DOM node before rendering something that depends on its size or position.

This is more or less [equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43842347/1535738) to calling `forceUpdate`.

Updated live example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sbilinski/69z2wepo/330677/).